# How to nullify box-shadow for bootstrap?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

in HTML5, I have `required` fields. When they are not filled, will be bordered, so far so good. I found out that if I add a `form-control` class, this behaviour wont work, because bootstrap changes the `box-shadow` css property.

How to nullify it? `box-shadow:none` wont help.

Answer (score 2):

Bootstraps uses vendor prefixes to make the box-shadow visible in different browsers. Make sure to set the box shadow with vendor prefixes to 'none' too.

```
.form-control {
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        -moz-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: Since you want to remove the box-shadow from your input fields using the .form-control class, add it to the .form-control class.

Comment: eeem, you meant "hack" into bootstrap?

Comment: You can simply add my edited code above AFTER the bootstrap.(min.).css

Comment: well, I directly put it into an input:

<input id="asdasdweb" class="form-control" type="text" required="required" value="http://www" name="web" style=" -webkit-box-shadow: none; -moz-box-shadow: none; box-shadow: none;">

with no effect